# Shortest Path using Dijkstra's Algorithm Output Question

Tags: c++, graph, tree, shortest-path, dijkstra

I was tasked to create a program that would output the shortest paths to all other nodes. So for example in this photo, with source A, ( https://www.includehelp.com/cpp-tutorial/Images/d0.jpg ) the output will be (unordered or ordered would be fine):




**A-B

A-C

A-B-G

A-B-G-E-D

A-B-G-E

A-B-G-E-F

..........**

Current Output:

```
AC ED BG E FD
```

*It shows the correct partial shortest paths but I just can't figure out how to somehow *connect* them.

So far, I have been able to compute the shortest path costs correctly from the source to each node using Dijkstra's Algorithm. However, I can't seem to figure out how to output the "connected path directions" as seen above.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>    
#include<vector> 
#include<string> 

using namespace std;
int src = 0;
int vertex;

struct node {
    string source;
    vector<string> dest;
    vector<int> cost;
};

int minimumcost(vector<int> cost, vector<bool> Cset, vector<node> Node);
void dijkstra(vector<vector<int>> graph, vector<node> Node);
vector<vector<int>> graph(vector<node> Node);
string delimiter(string temp);
void Print(vector<vector<string>> listed);

int main()
{
    vector<node> Node;
    vector<string> _dest,_dest1;
    string root;
    string temp1;
    string temp2;
    int cost;
    int i = 0;
    int check = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<i+1;){
            cin>>temp1;
            if(temp1 == "root"){
                cin>>root;
                break;
            }
            temp1 = delimiter(temp1);
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
                if(temp1 == Node[j].source){
                        cin>>temp2;
                        temp2 = delimiter(temp2);
                        Node[j].dest.push_back(temp2);
                        _dest.push_back(temp2);
                        cin>>cost;
                        Node[j].cost.push_back(cost);
                        check = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            if(check == 0){
                Node.push_back(node());
                Node[i].source = temp1;
                cin>>temp2;
                temp2 = delimiter(temp2);
                Node[i].dest.push_back(temp2);
                _dest.push_back(temp2);
                cin>>cost;
                Node[i].cost.push_back(cost);   
                i++;
                }
            check = 0;

        }


    sort(_dest.begin(), _dest.end() );
    _dest.erase( unique( _dest.begin(), _dest.end() ), _dest.end() );

    for(int i=0; i<_dest.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<Node.size(); j++){
            if(_dest[i] == Node[j].source){
                _dest.erase(_dest.begin()+i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<_dest.size(); i++){
        Node.push_back(node());
        Node[Node.size()-1].source = _dest[i];
    }

    vertex = Node.size();
    cout<<'\n';

    dijkstra(graph(Node),Node);
    cout<<'\n';
    return 0;                           
}


vector<vector<int>> graph(vector<node> Node){
int V = Node.size();
vector<int> temp(V, 0);
vector<string> elements;
vector<vector<int>> graph(V, temp);
     cout<<"  ";
    for(int i=0; i<V;i++){
        elements.push_back(Node[i].source);
    }

    cout<<'\n';
    for(int i=0; i<V;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<V;j++){
            for(int k=0; k<Node[i].dest.size();k++){
                if(Node[i].dest[k] == elements[j])
                   graph[i][j] = Node[i].cost[k];
            }
        }

    }

return graph;
}

string delimiter(string temp){
    if(temp != "root")
            temp[temp.size()-1] = '\0';
    return temp;
}


int minimumcost(vector<int> cost, vector<bool> Cset, vector<node> Node)  {

    int min = INT_MAX;                 
    int index;

    for(int v=0;v<vertex;v++)
    {
        if(Cset[v]==false && cost[v]<=min)      
        {
            min=cost[v];
            index=v;

        }
    }

    return index;
}

void dijkstra(vector<vector<int>> graph, vector<node> Node){
    vector<int> Cost(vertex,0);                  
    vector<bool> Cset(vertex,0);  
    vector<string> elements;
    vector<string> temp(1," ");
    vector<vector<string>> listed(vertex, temp);

    for(int i=0; i<vertex;i++){
        elements.push_back(Node[i].source);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++)                    
    {
        Cost[i]=INT_MAX;
        Cset[i]=false;  
    }

    Cost[src]=0;   

    for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++){
        int u=minimumcost(Cost,Cset,Node);
        Cset[u]=true;                
        for(int j=0;j<vertex;j++){
            if(!Cset[j] && graph[u][j] && Cost[u]!=INT_MAX && Cost[u]+graph[u][j]<Cost[j]){
                Cost[j]=Cost[u]+graph[u][j];
                if(graph[u][j] < graph[u][j-1]){
                    listed[i].push_back(elements[i]);
                    listed[i][listed[i].size()-2] = elements[j];
                }
                else
                    listed[i].push_back(elements[j]);
            }
        }

    }


    cout<<"Vertex\t\tCost from source"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++)                       
    {
        cout<<elements[i]<<"\t\t"<<Cost[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\n";     
    Print(listed);
    cout<<"\n"; 
}

void Print(vector<vector<string>> listed){
vector<vector<string>> temp;
for(int i = 0; i<vertex; i++)
    reverse(listed[i].begin(),listed[i].end());


    for(int i=0;i<listed.size();i++)                       
    {
        for(int j=0;j<listed[i].size();j++)     
            cout<<listed[i][j];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<listed.size();i++){
        temp.push_back({{0}});
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<listed[j].size();k++){
                temp[i].push_back(listed[j][k]);
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

Input:

```
A, B, 5
A, C, 3
D, A, 2
B, C, 2
C, D, 7
B, G, 1
B, E, 3
C, E, 7
E, D, 2
D, F, 6
G, E, 1
E, F, 1
root A
```

Please help. I'm stuck. Thank you.

Comment: *However, I can't seem to figure out how to output the "correct path directions"* -- Use the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset and single step through your program using it.

Comment: How is ABGED shortest path on that graph?

Comment: Hi! It's the shortest because it only costs 9 units to travel as compared to A-C-D that costs 10.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's digraph. I'm blind.

Comment: It's alright! Thank you for taking the time to review my problem. :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi! I'm not sure if I understood your suggestion correctly but from what I did, unfortunately, since it's not really a bug but is instead more of a logic problem, I'm not sure how that can be of much use. If you would please kindly help me connect the said partial paths, I would be eternally grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Well before you write any code, you should have worked out the logic with pencil and paper.  Then translate what is on pencil and paper to a program.  Then when the program doesn't behave as desired, you debug the program to see where it goes against your plan and make the appropriate adjustments -- this is how *all* programmers, student or professional, approaches a problem.  Right now, all you did was post your entire program and ask us to figure out what you're doing.  That's not the way it's supposed to work here.

Comment: I tend to agree with @PaulMcKenzie here. I just spent half an hour reading it (mainly as there are no source comments). Dijkskra is kinda easy to grasp, however what puzzled me is is FD connection specified in your question (should be FED, no pun intended) (as it originally seemed only closest edges are calculated). I assume we would have to be re-implemented to check, resulting in completely different code anyway.

Comment: @rAndom69 -- *resulting in completely different code anyway* -- And this is the risk of writing a program before working out all the details with pencil and paper / whiteboard / etc. first.  You wind up writing a lot of code, find out that there is a "feature" you left out or wanted to think about later, and then discover you have to start from scratch (or reimplement a lot of the code) to support such feature.